dotnet-Aspire testing Project autority port error using duende framework when using test project
I´m trying to implement the Identity Duende Framework on .NET Aspire and i´m stuck with the test project.
What happened is when i try to implement a code test to get client credentials like this sample:
Duende Documentation
The test fail because of Autority URL. I´ve notice the port when i run the test is different from the port settled in launchSettings. Because of that, the Web API refuses the connection.
I try to find something about url proxy in Aspire documentation and doesn´t find anything.
Anyone know how i can solve this ?
[Fact]
    public async Task GetAccessTokenValidScopeReturnsOKStatusCode()
    {
        // Arrange
        var appHost = await DistributedApplicationTestingBuilder.CreateAsync<Projects.AspireAppTest_AppHost>();
        
        await using var app = await appHost.BuildAsync();
        await app.StartAsync();

        // Act
        // discover endpoints from metadata
        var httpClient = app.CreateHttpClient("identity");
        var disco = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception(disco.Error);
        }

        // request token
        var tokenResponse = await httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "client1",
            ClientSecret = "secret1",
            Scope = "apiservice"
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        ...
    }

This code return OK result with token! But when i call this I've got the error:
   var apiHttpClient = app.CreateHttpClient("apiservice");
   apiHttpClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
   var response = await apiHttpClient.GetAsync("/user");

Error: "[Bearer error=""invalid_token"", error_description=""The issuer 'https://localhost:49635' is invalid""]"
The port is the problem, because the identity was setup to running over 5001 and not this dynamic port 49635 when using DistributedApplicationTestingBuilder

Can you post the actual error?

Sorry! I update the question with error message.

I believe the problem is to set fixed authority on Identity server! My doubt now is how to create a dynamic authority and detect if is test environment to set authority dynamically.
